# Methods and algorithms of load balancing web servers

Tags: algorithm, load-balancing

Picked up the thesis as "Methods and algorithms of load balancing web servers", but nothing new has been found and is now in a state of confusion. Much has already been invented but I just need something to improve or to come up with on this topic what is not now.
Please help to guide me in the right direction.

Comment: I don't think asking SO to write your thesis is going to end well.

Comment: Is the question to be understood more from a practical perspective, where one is interested in implementations in actual technical systems, or is the subject rather the study of scheduling algorithms for specific problems?